# Securing username and password passed as Environment variable

Tags: c, linux, bash, encryption, process

Username and Password are passed as plain text as environment variable while running a bash script from a existing process. using following command.

`sudo -u someuser USERNAME=abc PASSWORD=xyz /path/to/script/bashscript argument1 argument2`

Above bash script is user configurable script with username and password. the challenge i am facing above is, Environment variables are getting logged. like in auth.log which we don't want.

I am looking for ways to achieve one of the following:

1. To prevent it from logging(like into auth.log).
2. encrypt username and password in exiting process(c program) and pass as environment variable and have some way to decrypt it in bash script.

I tried looking solution for this. didn't found any which fit with my use-case. Can someone please help me with this? i will also like to know any other ways to make system more secure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify the script to read from from input and pass them by shell redirection of standard input using a “here” file. But this is a question for superuser.com, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Thanks for your response. these script are user configurable script and forked( and replaced by this script) by another process. so to provide input we need to feed it from parent process. we don't have mechanism for that. we creating many such processes in short regular intervals. we want to provide username/password while creating them . though i will think in that direction too if i can easily add that without using epoll.  
Also i will post this on superuser.com i was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit off-topic, but I will answer it anyway.

IMO, the proper way is to get rid from working with plain passwords at all. I'm pretty sure there might be multiple ways of achieving this, but these are the options which popped out in my head right now:

- Configure `sudoers`:

  Create `/etc/sudoers.d/user_a` with following:

  ```
  user_a ALL=(user_b:user_b) NOPASSWD:ALL
  ```

  Then whenever `user_a` executes `sudo -u user_b` password will not be required.
- Another way would be to use SSH keys and then run scripts locally via:

  ```bash
  ssh someuser@localhost "/path/to/script arg1 arg2"
  ```

Comment: Thanks Andrejs for reply. here username/password i not used to run script. its some credentials which can be used within the bash script. which is user configurable. i am providing a way to user so they won't need to write in username/password in plaintext in that script. instead get it as variable and use within program.